# Android: Requesting location permission from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-permissions, android-location

I have created a class `LocationProcess` that extends `AsyncTask` in a separate Java file.

With the `doInBackground()` method, I am trying to fetch the location coordinates (latitude and longitude) of the device. How and where to ask for permission, send location settings intent, etc. Please help.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ask for permission from your Activity before starting the AsyncTask. Execute the AsyncTask only if the permissions are granted and location is enabled.

Refrain from temptation to pass Activity reference to the AsyncTask, since it could cause memory leaks if not handled properly.

Its good practice to check whether permission is granted at lower level i.e. before accessing the API related to location, you can add simple check to verify if the permissions are granted.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I have asked for permissions in the MainActivity. What to do in `doInBackground()` method to fetch location coordinates? Please help.

Comment: @AdarshPunj you can find several tutorial like [this one](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html) for that. For the context of the question, remember to mark as accepted if it was useful, so that others can benefit too